# SOQL Query for Manually Assigned Accounts in a Territory

Tags: soql, account, developer-console, territory-management

The goal is to query all Manually Assigned Account on a particular Territory. If possible, a query that can be run through Developer Console/Workbench. Is this doable?

I can't seem to find anything that will help achieve this from this doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_territory2.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a separate documentation that might help others who encounters the same question:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_objectterritory2association.htm

Cheers!